# jsplumb - drag and drop connection from all side of a div

Tags: jsplumb

I am making a flowchart editor using jsplumb. In flowchart connector demo of jsplumb, we could make drag and drop connection from one side of div, i want that div to accept and make connection from all four sides.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want endpoints to move to any side of the div, then you should use Dynamic Anchors:

> These are Anchors that can be positioned in one of a number of locations, choosing the one that is most appropriate each time something moves or is painted in the UI.
>
> There is no special syntax to creating a DynamicAnchor; you just provide an array of individual Static Anchor specifications

To avoid that you can use Default Dynamic Anchor instead

> jsPlumb provides a dynamic anchor called "AutoDefault" that chooses from TopCenter, RightMiddle, BottomCenter and LeftMiddle

[image: Dynamic anchor]

For example when adding, endpoint can be specified like this:

```
        var anEndpoint = {
            endpoint: "Rectangle",
            isSource: true,
            isTarget: true,

            anchor:"AutoDefault"
        };
```

To try it, [use this fiddler](http://jsfiddle.net/DMINATOR/3HauW/1/)

[Refer to jsPlumb docs for more info](http://jsplumbtoolkit.com/doc/usage.html)

Answer (score 1):

use **endpointoption**

and set  **isSource:true, isTarget:true**

to make each endpoint play both role